# Is Strip Silence availible in all versions of Pro Tools including MP & SE

Tags: pro-tools, strip-silence, clients

I have a client who wishes to purchase an MP or SE version of Pro Tools to do basic scratch recordings at home. However due to here workflow it is critical that she has strip silence available to her. Is strip silence included in all Pro Tools Versions (SE & MP)

Answer (score 1):

Survey says!...

YES

I have used both, and it is there.

Good ol' Command+U